# Игра, работающая через setInterval, зависает

Tags: javascript, разработка-игр, backbone.js

Помогите пожалуйста найти причину, по которой игра зависает. Это выражается в невозможности переместить корабль игрока на более чем на 100px в любом направлении

Основной алгоритм игры следующий:
Для каждой сущности создан отдельный view:

```
APP.SpaceView       - содержит основную логику игры

APP.InformerView    - табличка, отображающая количество снарядов, жизненные силы, счёт и т.д.
APP.InfolineView    - бегущая строка с разной информацией
APP.FieldView       - игровая область(в ней летают корабли протвника, корабль игрока и звёзды)

APP.PlayerShipView    - корабль игрока
APP.PlayerRocketView  - снаряды игрока
APP.StarView          - звёзды на фоне
```

Большая часть логики на ходится в APP.SpaceView и организована так:
При инициализации этого view запускается основной цикл игры, в котором вычисляются координаты и условия для каждого объекта игры:

```
setInterval(function() {
  self._makeMoves(self)
}, 100);
```

в _makeMoves() вычисляются:
движения звёзд(перебор всей коллекции),
движение снарядов игрока
отслеживаются нажатия клавиш, отвечающих за перемещение корабля игрока и стрельбу

То есть каждую 0.1 сек происходит вычисление довольно большого количества опраций. Но не думаю, что в причина тормозов игры в этом. во-первых потому, что вычислений не так уж и много(ОЗУ 8гб). Во-вторых потому что я делал подобную игру таким же способом(на чистом js) и тоже с немалым количеством объектом и не было даже намёка на зависание

Помогите пожалуйста найти причину зависания

http://fh79272k.bget.ru/files/works/space/1/

https://github.com/zlodiak/space-1

Comment: Извините, но игра на div'ах в 2016-м - это какое-то извращение. Откройте уже для себя [Canvas](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API/Tutorial) и [`requestAnimationFrame`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame) и делайте нормальные игры. А если лень писать с нуля, используйте любой из [игровых движков](https://github.com/showcases/javascript-game-engines).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я так понял проблема в файле в **widgetsViews.js**.

В четвертой строке вы вешаете слушателя на изменение модели в методе **initialize**.


Каждые раз когда меняется модель(двигается корабль) слушатель повторно добавляется и в последствии идет большой перерасчет данных, который и тормозит игру.


Можно попробовать метод **listenToOnce** вместо **listenTo**.
После первого срабатывания событие удаляется, а не добавляется как это происходит с **listenTo**.


После десяти нажатий(двигал корабль вниз) в консоли [это](https://pp.vk.me/c636922/v636922314/6795/lRROv8Cuj9k.jpg). Это с **listenTo**.

После десяти нажатий(двигал корабль вниз) в консоли теперь [это](https://pp.vk.me/c636922/v636922314/679e/EgV8qG4fHVY.jpg). Это с **listenToOnce**.


После этих манипуляций игра перестала тормозить при перемещении.


Или можно проверять на наличие слушателя. Нету - добавили. Иначе ничего не делаем.


P.S. Backbone.js вижу впервые. Решение может оказаться не лучшим.